# Constructing GR tensors in the SME

Tags: general-relativity, field-theory, variational-principle, beyond-the-standard-model

In the Standard Model Extension (SME), the basic ingredients for the gravitational field is the vierbein $e^\mu_a$ and the spin connection $\omega^\mu_a$. 
In the zer-torsion (Riemannian) limit, we can write down the gravitational part of the action as
$$S = \int d^4x e ((1-u)R + s^{\mu\nu}R^T_{\mu\nu} + t^{\alpha\beta\mu\nu}C_{\alpha\beta\mu\nu}).$$

Given that we are in the zero-torsion limit, do we construct the tensors using the metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ or the vierbein?
Also, to the get the field equations, do we vary with the inverse metric? Some papers say that they do, but as the action already contains the vierbein $e$, I don't see how that is consistent.

Comment: It shouldn't matter. The vierbein is the "square root" of the metric.

Comment: Yes, but is it okay to mix them though? The action above, with e, is varied w.r.t inverse metric in one paper